# How to work with NSManagedObject in Swift

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I am working on a contact app so i have to add name and number to the custom tableview cell. I have to store that value using Core Data.

code in my view controller:

```
var name: [NSManagedObject]
var number: [NSManagedObject]
```

i have declared two variables so i cant return multiple value in the function of number of rows in section??

then i have added alert with two textfield where user can can register name and number

i have wrote function to save data to which retrieved from textfield:

```
  let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person",
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                 insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")

    do {
        try managedContext.save()

        names.append(person)
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

instead of using multiple values of var names and numbers i want declare that in single variable using `NSArray`. help me out to do this one

if i declare `NSArray` means i cant append the value of person

Comment: Why do you need the NSarray?

Comment: It seems to be a misunderstanding: There is a Core Data entity `Person` which has `name` and `number` attributes. If you want to display the data in a table view you have to declare **one** data source array `var people = [NSManagedObject]()` and get `name` and `number` of each record.

Comment: i will update and reply back..thank you

Comment: iam having two label in cell...name is parsing to first cell label box and number is parsing to second cell..dont know why??